# 'Half right' command seems not working when drawing Feynman diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman

Consider the folowing code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (x);
\vertex[right=of x] (y);
\vertex[above left=of x] (a);
\vertex[below left=of x] (b);
\vertex[above right=of y] (c);
\vertex[below right=of y] (d);

\diagram*{
    (x) --[fermion, half left] (y)
    (x) --[fermion, half right] (y)
    (x) --[fermion] (a)
    (x) --[fermion] (b)
    (y) --[fermion] (c)
    (y) --[fermion] (d)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is
[image]

but what I desired is the below one!

[image]

It seems that the `half right` command is not working. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the comma's after each edge in in `\diagram*`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (x);
\vertex[right=of x] (y);
\vertex[above left=of x] (a);
\vertex[below left=of x] (b);
\vertex[above right=of y] (c);
\vertex[below right=of y] (d);

\diagram*{
    (x) --[fermion, half left] (y),
    (x) --[fermion, half right] (y),
    (x) --[fermion] (a),
    (x) --[fermion] (b),
    (y) --[fermion] (c),
    (y) --[fermion] (d),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]